# Docker container unable to connect to postfix on host with error "MX Routing not available"

Tags: email, postfix, docker, email-server, alias

I'm trying to run a [SimpleLogin](https://simplelogin.io/) instance on my raspberry pi 4 (aka `armhf`/`armv7l`) following the [official instructions](https://github.com/simple-login/app#prerequisites), but the resulting installation isn't able to send emails to my real inbox.

I installed [swaks](https://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) inside the docker container `sl-app` where all the to-the-real-inbox emails originates, after trying to send a message i got this error

```
$ docker exec -ti sl-app swaks --from "REDACTED" --to "REDACTED"
*** MX Routing not available: requires Net::DNS.  Using localhost as mail server
=== Trying localhost:25...
*** Error connecting to localhost:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET: connect: Connection refused
```

It can't connect to the postfix installed on the host system

```
$ sudo systemctl status postfix
● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-12-22 19:11:26 GMT; 3h 10min ago
  Process: 21485 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21485 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The funniest thing is that a few days ago it worked just fine, the configuration hasn't changed but now it doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As the `systemctl status postfix` shows, your `postfix` is not running. Run `systemctl start postfix`.

The message `MX Routing not available` is not related. It indicates that you don't have `Net::DNS` Perl module required by `swaks` installed on your system.

Comment: I tried `systemctl start postfix` but nothing has changes: emails don't get sent and `systemctl status postfix` is identical. I've also tried to backup everything and completely reinstall simplelogin but i still stuck to the same swaks error

Comment: You need to find out why your `postfix` is not running/starting. It is a separate question. Until this is sorted out any manipulations with `swaks`  or `simplelogin` are meaningless.